# How to work through segmentation fault for "[For loop] variables"?

Tags: c, for-loop

I think I understand why I get the segmentation fault error (tie_count will be 0 and I tried to use it outside the loop). But how do I get to condition the variables that changed inside the loop after the loop has been finished?
or am i brain ded?

```
int x = 0, tie_count = 0, tie[8];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if ( //anything here )
    {
        //anything here
    }
    else
    {
        tie[x] = 1;
        x++;

        tie_count++;

    }
}

if (tie_count > 1)
{
    printf("%there is tie.\n");
}
else
{
    printf("no tie.\n");
}
```

Comment: The most probable cause of your problem is accessing a non-existing element of the array due to discrepancy between the declared size of an array and the range of iteration, as Cameron Tinker describes in the answer. Accessing the `tie_count` variable _after_ the loop has nothing to do with seg.fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are 0 based and you have a non-inclusive upper boundary of 10 on your loop condition. You have your `tie` array initialized as an integer array of length 8. This means that you're looping 10 times and the code may attempt to assign to an index that is larger than the array.

Without knowing the logic of your original if block, you need to either increase tie to have 10 elements or decrease your maximum loop value.

Try the following changes to suit your needs:

Either this:

```
int x = 0, tie_count = 0, tie[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

Or this:

```
int x = 0, tie_count = 0, tie[8];

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
```